# Get Owin authentication failure reason

Tags: c#, owin

I am using this code to authenticate users

```
TokenValidationParameters tokenParams = new TokenValidationParameters();

tokenParams.ValidAudiences = new List<string> { AUTH_VALID_AUDIENCE };
tokenParams.ValidateIssuer = true;
tokenParams.IssuerValidator = new IssuerValidator(IssuerValidator);

var options = new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
    TokenValidationParameters = tokenParams,
    Tenant = AUTH_OPTIONS_TENANT,
    MetadataAddress = string.Format(METADATA_ADDRESS_FORMAT, "login.windows.net")
};

app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(options);
```

Is there a way to log the failure reason(eg: the exception message)?
For example, if i use expired token, i get 401(unauthorized) but i could not find the reason(in that case: expired token) for the unauthorized response.